# Deploy a MEAN stack to public

Tags: node.js, networking, mean-stack

I'm new to the back-end side of development, but have figured out how to install the MEAN stack through a virtual server at DigitalOcean. I have shell access, and can properly deploy with `grunt` to "https://mydomain.com:3000". I also have my files uploaded to gitHub. This seems like a ridiculous question, but how do I create the web page "https://mydomain.com" without the port number so that everyone can access it?

I found this in gruntfile.js, which is the first file that runs.  Is this what I need to change (the 1337 to 443)?

```
    'node-inspector': {
        custom: {
            options: {
                'web-port': 1337,
                'web-host': 'localhost',
                'debug-port': 5858,
                'save-live-edit': true,
                'no-preload': true,
                'stack-trace-limit': 50,
                'hidden': []
            }
        }
    },
```

Dockerfile (no extension)

```
FROM dockerfile/nodejs

MAINTAINER Matthias Luebken, matthias@catalyst-zero.com

WORKDIR /home/mean

# Install Mean.JS Prerequisites
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN npm install -g bower

# Install Mean.JS packages
ADD package.json /home/mean/package.json
RUN npm install

# Manually trigger bower. Why doesnt this work via npm install?
ADD .bowerrc /home/mean/.bowerrc
ADD bower.json /home/mean/bower.json
RUN bower install --config.interactive=false --allow-root

# Make everything available for start
ADD . /home/mean

# currently only works for development
ENV NODE_ENV development

# Port 3000 for server
# Port 35729 for livereload
EXPOSE 3000 35729
CMD ["grunt"]
```

Comment: Listen on the [default port for HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Difference_from_HTTP), `443`.

Comment: The `3000` being used is specified somewhere within your application's code or configuration. [The `port` is required](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) for the HTTP/S Server to begin listening for network requests. And, a client/browser will use `443` with `https://` if a different port isn't given.

Comment: Is the file int the "dockerfile" ? See above.